# Canopy.us unable to connect to internet

Tags: ip, firewall

I’m trying to install canopy.us on my PC. Where I start canopy.us said that is unable to connect to internet.

I think this is the solution:
https://help.canopy.us/internet-safety-faq-devices-types/no-connection-in-school-network/

But how to add these ip in the firewall. I created Inbound Rule but didn’t work. What are these ip with “/“.